# Android Emulator is able to the Internet but the App is unable to connect to Firebase

Tags: android, flutter, intellij-idea, android-emulator

I'm trying to debug a Flutter app on an Emulator through AVD (Intellij). Everything works fine on a physical device. I can connect to the internet through the Emulator (Chrome browsing works) But I'm unable to connect to the Firebase server through the App in the emulator.

Here's the error stack trace

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:59768/9pXmC0Ic4uc=/ws
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
W/DynamiteModule( 6185): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found.
I/DynamiteModule( 6185): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0
W/ProviderInstaller( 6185): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
I/il.arnet_helpe( 6185): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
I/chatty  ( 6185): uid=10146(app.zumy.mil.arnet_helper) AsyncTask #1 identical 2 lines
I/il.arnet_helpe( 6185): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
...
**W/Firestore( 6185): (24.3.1) [OnlineStateTracker]: Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds
W/Firestore( 6185): 
W/Firestore( 6185): This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.
...**
>putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/il.arnet_helpe( 6185): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/Firestore( 6185): (24.3.1) [WatchStream]: (b4b5c28) Stream closed with status: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=Channel shutdownNow invoked, cause=null}.
W/DynamiteModule( 6185): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found.
I/DynamiteModule( 6185): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0
W/ProviderInstaller( 6185): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
W/ProviderInstaller( 6185): Failed to report request stats: com.google.android.gms.common.security.ProviderInstallerImpl.reportRequestStats [class android.content.Context, long, long]
W/DynamiteModule( 6185): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found.
I/DynamiteModule( 6185): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0
W/ProviderInstaller( 6185): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
W/ProviderInstaller( 6185): Failed to report request stats: com.google.android.gms.common.security.ProviderInstallerImpl.reportRequestStats [class android.content.Context, long, long]
W/DynamiteModule( 6185): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found.
I/DynamiteModule( 6185): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0
W/ProviderInstaller( 6185): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
W/ProviderInstaller( 6185): Failed to report request stats: com.google.android.gms.common.security.ProviderInstallerImpl.reportRequestStats [class android.content.Context, long, long]
D/EGL_emulation( 6185): eglMakeCurrent: 0xe0f191e0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe0f3e260)
W/DynamiteModule( 6185): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found.
I/DynamiteModule( 6185): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0
W/ProviderInstaller( 6185): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
W/ProviderInstaller( 6185): Failed to report request stats: com.google.android.gms.common.security.ProviderInstallerImpl.reportRequestStats [class android.content.Context, long, long]
```

I have added the following to /android/app/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

I have tried the cold boot option. It's not an issue with DNS because I CAN connect to the Internet through Chrome in the Emulator. I'm currently on Android 10.0 but I also tried 11. What could be missing?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an open unresolved [issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1794) with Firebase on Android emulators. So I gave up on running this on an emulator and instead using Edge (Web) instead to debug and continue with the development

Just make sure to pass in the options or else you WON'T be able to run your app on any browser or on Windows App. Here's the config needed for WEB.

```
Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```